# How to use Use Mixin $Variable in ngStyle?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm having a mixin variable in here:

**component.scss**

```
$bg-selected-list-item: #1E62F1; 
$bg-list-item: #FFF;
```

How can I use the above mixin variable in `[ngStyle`] here:

**component.html**

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let OBJ of dataSOURCE" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': OBJ.is_selected ? $bg-selected-list-item : (OBJ.back_color || $bg-list-item) }">
</mat-list-item>
```

**Expectation**

**Case 1** (If the ListItem is selected): then use the mixin variable `$bg-selected-list-item` as the background color of the list item

**Case 2** (If the ListItem is not selected & If the OBJ has back_color set)

->Then use the `OBJ.back_color` as the background color of the list item

**Case 3** (If the ListItem is not selected & If the OBJ has **NO** back_color set)

->Then use the mixin variable `$bg-list-item` as the background color of the list item.

Im facing the below problem

- Both The Mixin variable colors are not applied in the ngStyle**
- Only the OBJ.back_color** is applied.

> **BELOW is the ANSWER (thanks to @matirmv)**

**component.scss**

```
$bg-selected-list-item: #1E62F1; 
$bg-list-item: #FFF;

.my-background-class{
  background-color:$bg-list-item;
}
.my-background-selected-class{
  background-color:$bg-selected-list-item;
}
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let OBJ of dataSOURCE" class="my-background-class" [ngStyle]="!OBJ.is_selected && {'background-color': OBJ.back_color}"
                [ngClass]="{'my-background-selected-class': OBJ.is_selected}">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixin variables can't be used in the html template. As they are scss variables, you can only use them is your component.scss file.

The thing you have to do is pretty simple :

create a css class which uses the mixin you want for example :

```
$bg-selected-list-item: #1E62F1; 
$bg-list-item: #FFF;

.my-background-class{
  background-color:$bg-list-item;
}
.my-background-selected-class{
  background-color:$bg-selected-list-item;
}
```

Then go to your component.html file and use [ngClass] (not ngStyle which is only for css properties) :

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let OBJ of dataSOURCE" class="my-background-class" [ngClass]="{'my-background-selected-class': OBJ.is_selected">
</mat-list-item>
```

As you can see, the default class will be the .my-background-class, and if the list item is selected, the .my-background-selected-class will be added to change the background color.

That's it ! ;)

Comment: Thank you .. It solves Case-1 and Case-3. but what about Case 2: OBJ.back_color?

Comment: for this one you can use the ngStyle ;) sorry i forgot this one

Comment: I tried this-> class="my-background-class" [ngClass]="{'my-background-selected-class': OBJ.is_selected" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': OBJ.back_color}"> but the [ngStyle] overrides  [ngClass] and the selected color is not applied.

Comment: Thank you this is working-> [ngStyle]="!OBJ.is_selected && {'background-color': OBJ.back_color}"

Answer (score 1):

SASS variables are a compile time construct and not runtime property.
Angular will convert your template `html` into a pre-compiled (ngFactory) javascript class (AOT) to mitigate shipping the compiler with your app code. This results in better performance and faster rendering.

Hence, you need to define css classes which can be referenced by `ng-style` in the Angular compiled component at runtime.

Comment: so u mean, I can't directly use a mixin variable inside the ngStyle right?

Comment: Yes. `ng-style` will only work for references which will be available at runtime.